# How to detect a keycode and a click event in a single condition?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to write something like this:

```
function advance(e){
   if(e.keycode === 13 || e.target === 'click'){
    // something here
 }
}
```

http://jsbin.com/beracapede/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Attach the same handler to both key presses and clicks, then differentiate. To tell if it was clicked, you could check if the mouse button was down at the time of the event. There may be another event property that make detecting clicks easier too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check if the event is an instance of [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) or [`KeyboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent).

```js
function advance(event) {
  if (event instanceof MouseEvent) {
    console.log('clicked');
  } else if (event instanceof KeyboardEvent && event.keyCode === 13) {
    console.log('enter');
  }
}

window.addEventListener('keypress', advance);
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #F00;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="advance(event)"></div>
```